# Floating Hint of TextField while focus/click on Field

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a register page, and I have a small layout issue bothering me :

Here I have some TextFields inside Rows next to Icons. The hint text is aligned with the Icon, that's what I want, however once focused, the written text isn't aligned anymore. Is it possible to make it so the hint goes higher, resulting in an aligned written text ?

[image: The hint text is aligned with the Icon, however the written text isn't]

Thanks in advance for your answers

EDIT : here is the code for one row :

```dart
Row(
                children: [
                  const HeroIcon(
                    HeroIcons.atSymbol,
                    color: Colors.black45,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Focus(
                      onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
                        setState(() => _emailFieldColor =
                            hasFocus ? loginAccentColor : Colors.black45);
                      },
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: _email,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Email",
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: _emailFieldColor,
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: loginAccentColor,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: Please add code of text field.

Comment: @BijalSutariya here it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting the icon in a row widget, `InputDecoration` has a field called `prefixIcon` which takes in a widget which should function as you mentioned.

```
Expanded(
  child: Focus(
    onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
      setState(() => _emailFieldColor =
          hasFocus ? loginAccentColor : Colors.black45);
    },
    child: TextField(
      controller: _email,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Email",
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
          color: _emailFieldColor,
        ),
        focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: loginAccentColor,
          ),
        ),
        prefixIcon: const HeroIcon(
          HeroIcons.atSymbol,
          color: Colors.black45,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't align either, and it make the underline go under the logo. Thanks for the help though !

Comment: Hm I can't think of any good solutions. The text and icon will be aligned if you use `OutlineInputBorder()` if you want to try that, but that has a different look. Or an even jankier solution is to set `focusedBorder` to `OutlineInputBorder` and `border` to UnderlineInputBorder`, but that also doesn't look great when you focus it.

Comment: Yes, doesn't quite fit what I expected, I guess I'll go with that, I'm getting used to it and it's not a big deal anyway. Thx for your time !